# Как генерировать такие цвета?

Tags: css, color

Наткнулся на такой цвет **#ee00eeee**

Что это такое, обычно же все цвета обозначаются как **#ee00ee**

Comment: формат `rgba`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае использован формат `rgba`, в котором четвертый байт отвечает за прозрачность.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.back {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00f;
  left: 50px;
  top: -150px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rgb {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.rgba {
  background-color: #ff000088;
}
```

```html
<div class="rgb"></div>
<div class="rgba"></div>
<div class="back"></div>
```